# How to groupby time series by 10 minutes using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Have a time series(ts) indexed by DatatimeIndex, want to group it by 10 minutes

```
index   x  y  z

ts1     ....
ts2     ....
...
```

I know how to group by 1 minute

```
def group_by_minute(timestamp):
    year = timestamp.year
    month = timestamp.month
    day = timestamp.day
    hour = timestamp.hour
    minute = timestamp.minute
    return datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute)
```

then

```
ts.groupby(group_by_minute, axis=0)
```

my customized function (roughly)

```
def my_function(group):
    first_latitude = group['latitude'].sort_index().head(1).values[0]
    last_longitude = group['longitude'].sort_index().tail(1).values[0]
    return first_latitude - last_longitude
```

so the ts DataFrame should definitely contains 'latitude' and 'longitude' columns

When using TimeGrouper

```
   ts.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='100min')).apply(my_function)
```

I got the following errors,

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object
```

Comment: Have you tried `resample`? E.g. `df.resample('1min', 'mean')` What aggregation are you doing

Comment: @JoeCondron I am applying customized functions with APPLY function. It seems to me that resample or TimeGrouper fills in the gap automatically, even there is a time gap of one year. Is there a way to prevent from this ? Thanks a lot

Comment: You can pass your custom function like: `df.resample('10min', how=my_func)`. It won't fill gaps unless you tell it to. Maybe you should post the function you want to pass and desired output. Alternatively, you can adjust the last line of your function to `minute = 10 * (minute / 10)`.

Comment: @JoeCondron thanks for the suggestion. I have switched to resample and it almost works. Only resample takes the first column of df, does it apply to multiple columns of df at the same time ? I would reedit my function into the question. thx again

Answer (score 20):

There is a `pandas.TimeGrouper` for this sort of thing, what you described would be some thing like:

```
agg_10m = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='10Min')).aggregate(numpy.sum) #or other function
```

Comment: thx for the response. It seems that pd.TimeGrouper does exist, but isn't documented here http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html

Comment: oops, you are right. Never notice it is undocumented.

Comment: get an "TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object" by applying TimeGrouper

Comment: TimeGrouper is sort of documented -- it's in the cookbook  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#resampling  That's weird it doesn't seem to be covered outside of that though.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#grouping-with-a-grouper-specification is the canonical method for time grouping; this creates a TimeGrouper which is not public per se

Comment: Just leaving a note here that `TimeGrouper` is now deprecated, and [`Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) should be used instead

Answer (score 19):

I know this is old but pd.Grouper() will also accomplish this:

```
agg_10m = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='10Min')).aggregate(numpy.sum)
```

Comment: Now it is Grouper, because the old one is deprecated.