# Pandas resampling with minute frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 time series storedi n Panda dataframe.

The timestamp index are not synchronized. For example

```
print df_A
2017-01-31 15:10:10.210  39.05
2017-01-31 15:10:10.550  39.05
2017-01-31 15:10:10.680  39.05

print df_B
2017-01-31 15:10:18.140  6.49
2017-01-31 15:10:23.010  6.49
2017-01-31 15:11:12.630  6.49
```

I want to find the correlation between the time series, but first I must synchronize the time. My idea is to calculate the average price per minute.

How do I do this in Pandas?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32147224/how-to-groupby-time-series-by-10-minutes-using-pandas because the question shows how to group by minute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to groupby time series by 10 minutes using pandas?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32147224/how-to-groupby-time-series-by-10-minutes-using-pandas)